# ocp-ipm subscription key for QnA Maker

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am working with QnA Maker and i do not have idea how to get ocp-apim subscription key. I trying with endpoint key that that we get after publishing but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me how to get ocp-apim subscription key for the QnA maker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and navigate to your QnAMaker Cognitive Services resource in the Azure portal, and then click on the keys blade.

[image]